# Почему первый inline-block (с текстом) выпадает из строки?

Tags: html, css

В моем примере первый `inline-block` (с текстом) выпадает из строки. Параметр `vertical-align: top` исправляет ситуацию, но почему там происходит? Не понятно как добавление текста внутрь блока поломало конструкцию

```html
<style>
    .in1 {
     width: 120px;
     height: 120px;
     background-color: green;
     display: inline-block;
     margin-right: 10px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     background-size: cover;
    }
    
    .span {
     font-size: 12px;
     color: white;
     font-family: Tahoma;
    }
</style>
    
<div class="container1">
    <div class="in1"><span class="span">Some text</span></div>
    <div class="in1"></div>
    <div class="in1"></div>
    <div class="in1"></div>
    <div class="in1"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Пример на кодепене    http://codepen.io/Gaxak/pen/mAByRL

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в `span` свойство `position:absolute;`

```
.span {
    position:absolute;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white;
    font-family: Tahoma;
}
```

Comment: так же может решить проблему свойство `float:left;` в классе `in1`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но у меня просьба "на пальцах" объяснить, почему при добавлении текста, блок перенесся на другую строчку. Интересует именно причина такого переноса.